# generating a url with id in the middle for url_for tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the tag

```
<%= link_to('Local', url_for(:action => 'point_c', 
                             :gateway_id => gatewayid, 
                             :id => deviceid, 
                             :point_id => point.cn), :method => :post) %>
```

produces the url:

```
/inputs/point_c/5?gateway_id=f1486bee48c24765&point_id=22
```

but i need to create a url like:

```
/inputs/5/point_c?gateway_id=f1486bee48c24765&point_id=22
```

this is a shared page with multiple controllers accessing it, eg inputs,outputs etc.

**routes:**

```
resources :inputs do
  member do
    post :pointc
  end
end
```

**edit**:

this is from multiple controller so unable to use named routes. want the controller to be automatically generated

Comment: Post your routes.rb here

Comment: try `inputs_point_c_path(deviceid, :point_id => point.cn, :gateway_id => gatewayid)`? otherwise `rake routes` is your best friend